# How to fetch the last 7 days in the below output

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I'm running some API's on my builds and the output for the same is large. I make use of GREP to capture the required content in the output.

I now need to sort this output to capture only the last 7 days. Upon capturing the output for just the last 7 days, I shall be able to count my builds for the last 7 days. I need to perform a function wherein the PRESENTDATE -7 so that only those build values are present which ran in the last 7 days.

```
"lastStarted": "2019-05-03T03:26:35.705-400"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-03T03:19:38.705-500"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-02T03:18:55.709-950"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-02T08:36:55.655-955"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-02T09:33:45.705-700"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-02T02:22:35.705-300"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-01T01:59:22.705-800"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-01T07:07:36.705-320"
"lastStarted": "2019-05-01T06:11:44.705-960"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-30T08:22:35.705-600"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-30T09:26:55.705-900"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-29T01:26:55.105-700"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-28T02:26:50.205-100"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-27T05:36:10.705-200"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-27T09:26:20.905-300"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-27T06:55:30.505-700"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-26T07:12:35.405-800"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-26T02:32:55.605-600"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-25T22:53:59.205-500"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-24T89:54:23.305-700"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-23T12:12:20.655-100"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-22T56:55:35.725-200"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-21T98:57:28.855-300"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-21T99:56:38.635-600"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-21T21:36:59.955-200"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-19T09:46:19.675-800"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-18T02:56:38.325-705"
"lastStarted": "2019-04-17T19:36:35.705-700"
```

I need only those "lastStarted" in my output which are 7 days behind the current date. Like in the above example, only lastStarted till 2019-04-27 will be required. The others need to be removed. I shall then couunt these values and get the number of builds that ran in the last week.

Comment: Is your actual input in JSON format?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, the actual input is in JSON.

{
    "uri": "http://localhost:8081/abc/api/build"
    "builds" : [
    {
        "uri" : "/my-build",
        "lastStarted" : "2019-04-18T02:56:38.325-705"
    },
    {
        "uri" : "/sample",
        "lastStarted" : "2019-05-02T08:36:55.655-955"
    }

Comment: take a look at [tag:jq] then, we use it to parse JSON rather then line oriented tools like grep

Comment: I'm using jq length to calculate the number but before that, I'll have to sort this output for the last one week.

Comment: well you can do that in jq, that's why I asked you if input is JSON

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the actual JSON, so I'm going to assume the following JSON and use it as input.

'*so_55981304.json*':

```
{
  "uri": "localhost:8081/abc/api/build",
  "builds": [
    {
      "uri": "/my-build",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-17T19:36:35.705-700"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample1",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-18T02:56:38.325-705"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample2",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-19T09:46:19.675-800"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample3",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-21T21:36:59.955-200"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample4",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-21T99:56:38.635-600"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample5",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-21T98:57:28.855-300"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample6",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-22T56:55:35.725-200"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample7",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-23T12:12:20.655-100"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample8",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-24T89:54:23.305-700"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample9",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-25T22:53:59.205-500"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample10",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-26T02:32:55.605-600"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample11",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-26T07:12:35.405-800"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample12",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-27T06:55:30.505-700"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample13",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-27T09:26:20.905-300"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample14",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-27T05:36:10.705-200"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample15",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-28T02:26:50.205-100"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample16",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-29T01:26:55.105-700"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample17",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-30T09:26:55.705-900"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample18",
      "lastStarted": "2019-04-30T08:22:35.705-600"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample19",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-01T06:11:44.705-960"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample20",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-01T07:07:36.705-320"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample21",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-01T01:59:22.705-800"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample22",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-02T02:22:35.705-300"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample23",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-02T09:33:45.705-700"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample24",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-02T08:36:55.655-955"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample25",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-02T03:18:55.709-950"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample26",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-03T03:19:38.705-500"
    },
    {
      "uri": "/sample27",
      "lastStarted": "2019-05-03T03:26:35.705-400"
    }
  ]
}
```

(Note: `"2019-04-21T99:56:38.635-600"`, `99` hours... really?! This isn't a valid [dateTime](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#date-time-values).)

[Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), a HTML/XML/JSON parser (using CSS, XPath, XQuery, JSONiq and pattern templates), can do what you want.

```
xidel -s so_55981304.json --xquery '
  for $x in $json/(builds)()
  where $x/lastStarted lt current-dateTime() - duration("P7D")
  order by $x/lastStarted
  return $x
'
```

This returns all the objects from the `builds`-array untill `current-dateTime() - duration("P7D")` (`2019-04-27T14:22:40.359` at the moment).
Also note that `order by $x/lastStarted` is needed, because (assuming your list of `lastStarted` attributes in your original post) they're not sorted correctly.

To count these objects simply put `count(` `)` around the query:

```
xidel -s so_55981304.json --xquery '
  count(
    for $x in $json/(builds)()
    where $x/lastStarted lt current-dateTime() - duration("P7D")
    order by $x/lastStarted
    return $x
  )
'
```

This returns `15`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 grep $(date --date="7 days ago" "+%Y-%m-%d") myfile
```

Comment: "*...only lastStarted till 2019-04-27 will be required. The others need to be removed.*". Your solution does exactly the opposite.